# node.js prompt: how to diable the appearance of the word 'prompt'?

Tags: node.js, prompt

I use npm package 'prompt' - https://www.npmjs.com/package/prompt. 
What I dislike in this package is that whenever the code waits for a user input it prints the word 'prompt:' in console.

For example, the code:

```
 var prompt = require('prompt');
  prompt.start();
  prompt.get(['username', 'email'], function (err, result) {
    console.log('Command-line input received:');
    console.log('  username: ' + result.username);
    console.log('  email: ' + result.email);
  });
```

will print to console:

> **prompt**: username: some-user
>   **prompt**: email: some-user@some-place.org
>
> Command-line input received:
>       username: some-user
>       email: some-user@some-place.org

I don't want to see the word 'prompt' whenever the console wait for user input. Do you know how it can be disabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/prompt#customizing-your-prompt), you simply set `prompt.message` and `prompt.delimiter`.